# Can I search for an object by its name within a form in VB6?

Tags: vb6, search-form

As declared in the title, for example, I want to search for a button whose name is `button8`, within a form where there are so many buttons that I do not want to check the name one by one.

Can I do this in VB6?

Comment: Is this when editing the project in the IDE, or in your code when executing at runtime?

Comment: I mean, when I am editing in the IDE, I can easily find the code corresponding to the specified button (just double click the button on the form). But, what can I do in the reversed way? I can not double click the code if I want to find the corresponding button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to find a control in the form designer, if you know the name.

Go to the form designer, open the property window (press F4), and use the dropdown to choose the control. This shows the properties in the window (and you can edit them). It also selects the control onscreen.

Answer (score 4):

You should just be able to refer to the control via the controls collection, like so:

```
Me.Controls("Button8")
```

[See this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e4daa9c%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).